# Syntax error in Postgres SQL when creating a trigger for a function I've defined?

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, triggers

Using this SQL:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS notify_new_proposed_game();
CREATE FUNCTION notify_new_proposed_game()
RETURNS void
AS 'NOTIFY proposed_game, ''new'';'
LANGUAGE SQL;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS new_proposed_game ON game;
CREATE TRIGGER new_proposed_game
AFTER INSERT
ON game
EXECUTE FUNCTION notify_new_proposed_game();
```

I get this error:

```
DROP FUNCTION
CREATE FUNCTION
psql:schema.sql:27: NOTICE:  trigger "new_proposed_game" for relation "game" does not exist, skipping
DROP TRIGGER
psql:schema.sql:31: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FUNCTION"
LINE 4: EXECUTE FUNCTION notify_new_proposed_game();
```

and I'm not sure why.

I'm between novice and intermediate with SQL, so it could well be something really simple.

The function works when called manually in PSQL.

Desired result:

- no error
- trigger is set up

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems:

1. Syntax: you must be using an old version of PostgreSQL where you cannot use `EXECUTE FUNCTION`, but only `EXECUTE PROCEDURE` in the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement.
2. Trigger functions cannot be written in SQL. You must use PL/pgSQL or some other procedural language.
3. Your trigger function must `RETURNS trigger`, not `void`. Make sure to `RETURN NEW;` in the function.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer! I'm using version 12.4 and the docs suggest `EXECUTE PROCEDURE` is deprecated?

2 and 3 make a lot of sense and I'm going to try them:)

Comment: You also forgot `FOR EACH ROW`.